# Weighted average mean $M_r^{\lambda}$ is convex function

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ be positive real numbers and $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$ is such that $\lambda_i> 0$ with $\lambda_1+\dots+\lambda_n=1$. Define $$M_r^{\lambda}=\begin{cases}
(\lambda_1 a_1^r+\lambda_2 a_2^r+\dots+\lambda_n a_n^r)^{1/r}, & \text{if }r\neq 0, \\
a_1^{\lambda_1}a_2^{\lambda_2}\dots a_n^{\lambda_n}, & \text{if }r=0.
\end{cases}$$

Prove that the function $M_r^{\lambda}$ is convex for $r<0$ and concave for $r>0$.

I think that the proof of each of them is really similar. I am trying to handle the case when $r<0$.

**Claim:** $M^{\lambda}(r)$ is convex function for $r<0$.

I need to show that for $r_1,r_2<0$ and $\alpha,\beta\geq 0$ with $\alpha+\beta=1$ we have: $$M^{\lambda}(\alpha r_1+\beta r_2)\leq \alpha M^{\lambda}(r_1)+\beta M^{\lambda}(r_2).$$

But I have no idea how to prove this inequality. I am writing everything in detail but it is getting really complicated.

Comment: Please check $n=2, a_1=2, a_2 = 3, t_1 = \frac{1}{3}, t_2 = \frac{2}{3}$, that is $M(r) = (\frac{1}{3}2^r + \frac{2}{3}3^r)^{1/r}$. Check the 2nd derivative of $M(r)$ for $r\in (-1, 0)$.

Comment: @RiverLi, Hey! I was trying to compute its second derivative but it looks really messy. Could you show your own computation, please? I will appreciate your help!

Comment: You may use https://www.wolframalpha.com/, for example, input: plot(diff(diff(((1/3)*2^r+(2/3)*3^r)^(1/r), r), r), r = -1 .. 0)

Comment: @RiverLi, Thanks! it shows that the second derivative is negative, right? Which means that $M(r)$ is concave in this case. So you mean that my claim is false, right?

Comment: I guess that it is convex for $r < c$ for some $c < 0$ (rather than $r < 0$), and concave for $r > 0$. I do not have a proof.